# SIFT KeyPoint input values (scale constants)

Tags: point-cloud-library, sift

I am using PCL and need some help for setting the appropriate constant values while computing **SIFT KeyPoints - minimum contrast, number of octaves, scales per octave**. From the sift code, I understood that minimum scale is the voxel/leaf size, but other constants are not clear. The original research paper by **Lowe** on SIFT KeyPoints is based on *image processing* and I'm still trying to contextualize that for *point cloud processing*. I don't have any background in image processing. All the open source examples on the internet give some fixed values to these constants, but I think that they should be a function of the input point cloud. Any suggestions for the same? I also searched for some reference material on the internet to understand the nexus between images and point cloud (in the context of SIFT KeyPoints), but haven't found any thus far.

`constexpr float minimumContrast = 1e-3f; constexpr int numberOctaves = 3, scalesPerOctave = 4;`

These are the commonly used values, but I don't understand the logic behind using those values. I even get a result after setting these values, but I'd like to tune them so as to extract the optimal keypoints.